# Preview of a proposed edit?

Tags: support, feature-request, review, suggested-edits, review-audit

Is there a way, when reviewing a proposed edit, to preview it exactly as the edited text would appear on the site?  I maybe wrong but I think that at Tex/LaTeX Stackexchange you have the option to see the original answers / suggested edit either as the code or how they will look on the screen. I used the "improve" option for this purpose a couple of times but then I got insulted that I failed the idiot test since what was I thinking trying to improve an already rejected edit!  So what is a good way to see the proposed edits in full glory before reaching a conclusion?

**Feature requested**: We should be able to see the edit **side by side** with the original question either as code or as final screen output depending on what we click (I maybe mistaken but I think Tex/LaTeX SE already has this capability).

Comment: I generally spend a few seconds trying to judge whether it's an audit -- suggested edit audits are very easy to recognise due to the gibberish they insert into posts, as well as hardly ever delete anything. After that, proceed as normal. That's a workaround, but I agree that there should be a full preview instead of the "diff" -- especially for TeX, it can be hard to judge correctness.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Audits: this is getting ridiculous.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11641/audits-this-is-getting-ridiculous)

Comment: Forget about audits: it is really cumbersome to not be able to see how an edit would look like with all the colors and LaTeX code. Why can we have the proposed output of the edit displayed below as in the answes? This is IMHO the main point of the question.

Comment: @Lord_Farin On the other hand, the gibberish they insert into post is precisely what makes me click "Improve" to see the post because the diff does not seem to make any sense at all, and I immediately think that the diff is to blame for the gibberish.

Comment: Is this something we could do ourselves or do we have to ask on Meta.SE, @JyrkiLahtonen (or another mod who knows about this)?

Answer (score -1):

I have another reason I wish to preview an edit.  I made [a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742588/if-k-cap-bbb-qcycl-bbb-q-zeta-m-and-k-bbb-q-galois-then-galk-zeta), which was edited by someone else.  The edit went through, but the formatting looked a lot worse than what I had; for example, the math didn't fit on one line, and had like a } on its own separate line.

So I made a comment to that person, and he is now trying another edit.  However, it looks like he didn't address the issue he created, but instead changed more things that looked alright as it was.  How can I preview the post to see what it would look like, before deciding whether or not to accept his second edit?

Comment: If you have a different yet related question, posting a new question is the way forward. Include a link to this thread if beneficial.